# Are there interior guided tours of the Seven Sisters?

Tags: tours, architecture, moscow

The [Seven Sisters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Sisters_(Moscow)) (*Stalinskie Vysotki*) are a set of seven famous Moscow skyscrapers built in the Stalinist style.  Apart from the [Galina Ulanova Museum](http://galinaulanova.com/museum/) in the Kotelnicheskaya Embankment Building, are there any times at which members of the public are offered guided tours of the interior of any of the buildings?

I realize that all seven buildings are in use as apartments, hotels, offices, etc., and so their occupants may not want tourists tramping around all the time.  But on the other hand, many organizations or entire cities do have occasional "open house" nights (such as the annual [Open House London](http://www.openhouselondon.org.uk/) festival) where it is possible to tour buildings that are normally closed to the public.  Perhaps Moscow also has such a festival that includes some of the Seven Sisters?

Answer (score 2):

You may have some luck with the Moscow State University building:

- It has a museum (I think [this is the one](http://www.mes.msu.ru/)). Unfortunately it's not open to individual visitors (except for MSU students / staff), but it is open to organized tours, and it's located pretty high up in the MSU building. You may be able to find a tour company that can organize a tour here (or if you're willing to go through the bureaucracy you can organize one yourself).
- From what I saw (admittedly many years ago), if you look like a student and enter the building through one of the auxiliary/side entrances, chances are nobody will check your student ID and you will be able to get in. However, security may be tighter now.
- Being an active university, I wouldn't be surprised if MSU hosts some events/lectures open to the public, which may offer a legitimate way to get into the building. I don't know any specifics though.